# Flash- circle not rotating inside another circle

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make the small circles to be able to rotate inside the large circle. But what i got is that the small circles are rotating outside the large circle.
Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var Rec:Number=-1;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EntFrame);

function EntFrame(e:Event):void
{
    if (Rec == -1)
    {
        CircleL.rotation-= 2;
    }
}

var cenX = CircleL.x;
var cenY = CircleL.y;

var ccStep = .01;
var twoPI = 2 * Math.PI;
var circleSNum1:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum2:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum3:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum4:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum5:Number = Math.random();

function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}

var radius1 = randomRange(10, 90);
var radius2 = randomRange(10, 90);
var radius3 = randomRange(10, 90);
var radius4 = randomRange(10, 90);
var radius = randomRange(10, 90);

function move(event:Event):void
{
    CircleL.CircleS1.x = cenX + Math.cos(circleSNum1 * twoPI) * radius;
    CircleL.CircleS1.y = cenY + Math.sin(circleSNum1 * twoPI) * radius;

    CircleL.CircleS2.x = cenX + Math.cos(circleSNum2 * twoPI) * radius2;
    CircleL.CircleS2.y = cenY + Math.sin(circleSNum2 * twoPI) * radius2;

    CircleL.CircleS3.x = cenX + Math.cos(circleSNum3 * twoPI) * radius3;
    CircleL.CircleS3.y = cenY + Math.sin(circleSNum3 * twoPI) * radius3;

    CircleL.CircleS4.x = cenX + Math.cos(circleSNum4 * twoPI) * radius4;
    CircleL.CircleS4.y = cenY + Math.sin(circleSNum4 * twoPI) * radius4;

    CircleL.CircleS5.x = cenX + Math.cos(circleSNum5 * twoPI) * radius1;
    CircleL.CircleS5.y = cenY + Math.sin(circleSNum5 * twoPI) * radius1;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move);
```

Here is how it looks like when I run it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely the way your circles are nested and how you do the calculation.

The `.x` and `.y` of a `DisplayObject` properties are always with respect to the origin of the parent. Looking at your code:

```
CircleL.CircleS1
CircleL.CircleS2
```

All the smaller circles have the bigger one as a container. Your calculation however:

```
cenX + Math.cos(circleSNum1 * twoPI) * radius;
// aka
CircleL.x + Math.cos(circleSNum1 * twoPI) * radius;
```

starts with adding the coordinates of the parent. This is in contradiction to the above, because "with respect to their parent" already includes the term `CircleL.x`. You have two options:

1. Keep the code, but move all the smaller circles outside their parent, so that they are "siblings" of the big circle.
2. Keep the structure, but change the code to accommodate for that structure and remove the position of the parent from the calculation.

Comment: Can i ask why does stop() or play() couldn't work on my code? isit because i am using var Rec:Number=-1; make the animation?

Comment: @Darren: please don't ask new questions in comments. Create a new question. Is the problem with the circles solved now?